# Get latest record from a table based on 2 columns in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to get the latest record from my source table based on **num** and **id** columns and insert in my target table.

Scenario is explained in the attached screen shot. For latest record date column can be used.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPzjz.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select num,id, date
FROM
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by num,id Order by date desc) as rnk
FROM source_table
)a
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

by using corelated Subquery

```
 select * from your_table t 
   where t.date= (
                 select max(date) from your_table t1 
                 where t1.num=t.num and t1.id=t.id
                 )
```

You can do it using `max()` function

```
select num,id,max(date) from your_table t
group by num,id
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT NUM,ID,DATE FROM TABLE_TEMP
QUALIFY RANK OVER(PARTITION BY NUM,ID ORDER BY DATE DESC)=1;
```

You can do this using single line query

SELECT NUM,ID,DATE FROM TABLE_TEMP
QUALIFY RANK OVER(PARTITION BY NUM,ID ORDER BY DATE DESC)=1;